# not able to update to update table as it is used in from clause in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE qn_answers
SET `GRADE` = -100
WHERE `QSN_ID` IN (SELECT q.`ID` FROM `questions` q
LEFT JOIN qn_answers qa ON q.`ID` = qa.`QSN_ID`
WHERE q.`QSN_TYPE_ID` = 3 AND qa.`ISCORRECT` = 0 AND qa.`GRADE` = 0);
```

I'm trying to update a column based on the result from the join table , but  it gives ERROR : 1093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want an update join here, without a subquery:

```
UPDATE qn_answers qa
INNER JOIN questions q
    ON qa.QSN_ID = q.ID
SET GRADE = -100
WHERE
    q.QSN_TYPE_ID = 3 AND
    qa.ISCORRECT = 0  AND
    qa.GRADE = 0;
```

The error message has to do with that you are using the target table `qn_answers` as part of the join.  You can't do this directly in a MySQL update.

Answer (score 0):

use `join update`

```
UPDATE qn_answers a
join 
(SELECT q.`ID` FROM `questions` q
LEFT JOIN qn_answers qa ON q.`ID` = qa.`QSN_ID`
WHERE q.`QSN_TYPE_ID` = 3 AND qa.`ISCORRECT` = 0 AND qa.`GRADE` = 0
) b on a.`QSN_ID`=b.`ID`
SET `GRADE` = -100
```

Answer (score 0):

I think standard update also will work here. Try this:

```
UPDATE qa
SET `GRADE` = -100
FROM 
`questions` q
LEFT JOIN
`qn_answers` qa
ON
q.`ID` = qa.`QSN_ID`
WHERE q.`QSN_TYPE_ID` = 3 AND qa.`ISCORRECT` = 0 AND qa.`GRADE` = 0;
```